# SQL - Fetch rows where quantity = 0 (Group By)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

from this result set I only want to fetch `req_id's` which **only** have 0 for quantity. Note that there could be multiple rows with same `req_id`

```
req_id | quantity

kcm01   0
kcm02   1
kcm02   0
kcm02   0
kcm02   4
kcm03   4
kcm03   5
kcm03   0
kcm05   0
kcm05   0
```

I only want a result like below,

```
req_id

kcm01
kcm05
```

Here's what I tried, but it did not give me desired results. Thank you for helping.

```
select req_id from t
group by req_id, quantity
having max(quantity) = 0
```

Comment: Don't group by quantity - that will create a group for almost every row in your results

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get to the solution.

```
select req_id 
  from t
group by req_id
having max(quantity) = 0
   and count(distinct quantity)=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct req_id 
from table t1
where quantity = 0
and not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.req_id = t1.req_id and t2.quantity <> 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separate `req` table, then the most efficient method is probably:

```
select r.*
from reqs r
where not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where t.req_id = r.req_id and t.quantity <> 0
                 );
```